# How to mirror a column that has merged cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm working on a "consolidated grid" spreadsheet. It has sheets for each project and then a main grid that lists statuses from each sheet.  Everything works great unless the project sheet happens to have merged cells like this:

[image]

This causes the consolidated grid to look like this:

[image]

This is because the grid is referencing: (F1 contains the sheet name)

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'",F$1,"'!F12"))
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'",F$1,"'!F13"))
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'",F$1,"'!F14"))
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'",F$1,"'!F15"))
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'",F$1,"'!F16"))
```

Whereas the project cells are now ordered like:

```
F12
F13
F14
F16
F17
```

I'm just looking for basic ideas on how to resolve this.  Keep in mind that the project tasks with multiple lines won't always be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have discovered one of the (many) disadvantages of using merged cells. Any formulas that use cell references in sequence will fail when merged cells are involved, since the merged cell address uses only the top left cell to reference the whole merged range. Cell references contained in the merged range will return a zero.

That is how merged cells work.

You will need to change your formula so that it looks up the value based on the task name in the Milestone column on the Project sheet. This also means you can't have duplicate task names, because only the first matched task will be returned, but you can continue to use merged cells.

Consider the following screenshot:

[image]

The formula in cell B2 and copied down is

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&$F$1&"'!F:F"),MATCH(A2,INDIRECT("'"&$F$1&"'!E:E"),0))
```

Adjust cell references as required.

Comment: Perfect!  And not as complex as I feared! You're my hero!